# Robot in a Grid - how to get all possible paths

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> There is a grid with with r rows and c columns. A robot sitting in top left cell can only move in 2 directions, right and down. But certain cells have to be avoided and the robot cannot step on them. Find a path for the robot from the top left to the bottom right.

The problem specifically asks for a single path, and that seems straight forward:

Having the grid as `boolean[][]`, the pseudocode I have is

```java
List<String> path = new ArrayList<String>()
boolean found = false

void getPath(r, c){
    if (!found) {

      if ( (r or c is outofbounds) || (!grid[r][c]) )
          return

      if (r==0 AND c==0)  // we reached
           found = true

      getPath(r-1, c)
      getPath(r, c-1)

      String cell = "(" + r + ", " + c + ")"
      path.add(cell)

    }    
}
```

Though I was wondering how can I get **all the possible** paths (NOT just the count, but the path values as well). Note that it has r rows and c columns, so its not a nxn grid. I'm trying to think of a DP/recursive solution but unable to come up with any and stuck. It's hard to think when the recursion goes in two ways.

Any pointers? And also any general help on how to "think" about such problems would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any pointers? And also any general help on how to "think" about such problems would be appreciated :).

Approach to the problem:

1. **Mentally construct graph** G of the problem. In this case the vertices are cells in the grid and directed edges are created where a valid robot move exist.
2. **Search for properties** of G. In this case G is a **DAG** (Directed Acyclic Graph).
3. **Use such properties** to come up with a solution. In this case (G is a DAG) its common to use **topological sort** and **dynamic programming** to find the amount of valid paths.

Actually you don't need to construct the graph since the set of edges is pretty clear or to do topological sort as usual iteration of the matrix (incremental row index and incremental column index) is a topological sort of this implicit graph.

The dynamic programming part can be solved by storing in each cell `[x][y]` the amount of valid paths from `[0][0]` to `[x][y]` and checking where to move next.
**Recurrence:**
[image: 1]

After computations the answer is stored in `dp[n - 1][m - 1]` where `n` is amount of rows and `m` is amount of columns. Overall runtime is `O(nm)`.

How about find all possible valid paths:
Usual backtracking works and we can speed it up by applying early pruning. In fact, if we calculate `dp` matrix and then we do backtracking from cell `[n - 1][m - 1]` we can avoid invalid paths as soon the robot enters at a cell whose `dp` value is zero.

Python code with `dp` matrix calculated beforehand:

```py
n, m = 3, 4
bad = [[False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]]
dp = [[1, 1, 1, 1], 
      [0, 0, 1, 2], 
      [0, 0, 1, 3]]

paths = []
curpath = []
def getPath(r, c):
    if dp[r][c] == 0 or r < 0 or c < 0:
        return
    curpath.append((r, c))
    if r == 0 and c == 0:
        paths.append(list(reversed(curpath)))
    getPath(r - 1, c)
    getPath(r, c - 1)
    curpath.pop()

getPath(n - 1, m - 1)
print(paths)

# valid paths are [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3)], 
#                  [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)], 
#                  [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3)]]
```

Notice that is very similar to your code, there is a need to store all valid paths together and take care that appended lists are a copy of `curpath` to avoid ending up with an list of empty lists.

Runtime: `O((n + m) * (amount of valid paths))` since simulated robot moves belong to valid paths or first step into an invalid path detected using foresight (`dp`). Warning: This method is exponential as amount of valid paths can be [image: 2].

Comment: What you explained makes sense, and it can be used to calculate the **total no. of paths**, but it would return a matrix like `[[0, 1, 1][1, 2, 3][1, 3, 6]]` (for 3 rows 3 cols), but how can I deduce the actual path values from this matrix? i.e. the 6 paths in the case.

Comment: @Ufder As number of paths could be up to combination of (n + m) elements taken n at a time without repetition the best runtime when iterating for all valid paths is to do backtracking with O(1) pruning (invalid paths are those who step in a cell whose dp value is zero). Its better to start the backtraking from cell [n-1][m-1] to [0][0] in order to prune right when you are creating an invalid path.

Comment: Thanks again, but maybe I didn't make myself clear. I am backtracking indeed, starting at the last cell and ending at (0,0) i.e. doing a bottom up recursion. I am able to get the counts just fine. But I am not clear on how do I get the actual paths, eg. `[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2,1), (2, 2)]]` where as an example there are 2 paths containing the cell addresses from start to end. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: @Ufder I edited the answer to fit your whole question :-)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, much appreciated! Let me spend some time and try to understand this and then accept the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the help, this helps, in my implementation of your explanation I was doing `curpath = []` instead of just popping! Can this be memoized to make it better w.r.t. runtime?

Comment: @Ulder That's actually the tight bound so there are no further improvements when displaying all valid paths.

Comment: Makes sense. If I am just getting one path as asked in the actual problem, then I can add memoization and stop after finding the first path, but here we have to go through all paths to find all paths :). Thanks for the help, just trying to learn and understand by going outside the scope of the problem!